# Undefined Reference to 'blink'

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I am making an .img for the RPI-4 etc. I have a main init.c file that transforms into a binary and to an img.
Now I want to incorporate another .c file named 'src/dev-gpio.c'. This file contains a blink() function that gets called in init.c's main loop.

dev-gpio.c :

```
#include "eos.h"
void blink()
{ 
...
}
```

eos.h :

```
#ifndef EOS_H
#define EOS_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
...
extern void blink();
#endif
```

makefile:

```
    .PHONY: all build clean

build/rapi-boot/eos-init.bin: build/obj/init.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o eos-init.elf -nostdlib -fno-pie -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -T linker.ld -e start build/obj/init.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-objcopy eos-init.elf -O binary -j .eos-* build/rapi-boot/eos-init.bin
    rm eos-init.elf

build/obj/init.o: src/init.c src/eos.h 
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o build/obj/init.o -c -fno-pie -ffreestanding src/init.c

build: build/rapi-boot/eos-init.bin
    dd if=/dev/zero of=build/eos.img count=100 bs=1M
    sudo losetup -D
    sudo losetup -fP build/eos.img
    printf "o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nt\nc\nw\n" | sudo fdisk /dev/loop0
    sudo losetup -o 1048576 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop0
    sudo mkfs.vfat -n EOS /dev/loop1
    sudo mount /dev/loop1 build/mnt
    sudo cp -r build/rapi-boot/* build/mnt/.
    sudo umount build/mnt
    sudo losetup -D

clean:
    if [ -f "build/rapi-boot/eos-init.bin" ]; then rm build/rapi-boot/eos-init.bin; fi
    if [ -f "build/eos.img" ]; then rm build/eos.img; fi
    if [ -f "build/obj/init.o" ]; then rm build/obj/*.o; fi
    if [ -f "build/obj/dev-gpio.o" ]; then rm build/obj/*.o; fi
```

How would I go about adding this dev-gpio.c file to makefile so my init.c can see the blink() function? No matter what I do I get undefined reference to blink() in my init.c.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 1) Figure out how to build `dev-gpio.o` on the command line. 2) Once you have that working, write a rule to do it. 3) Modify the linking command (`aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc ...`) in the `eos-init.bin` rule, probably just by appending the "dev-gpio.o" filename (with path) to the end of the command.

Comment: I have now added this rule to compile dev-gpio.o:
`build/obj/dev-gpio.o: src/dev-gpio.c src/init.o src/eos.h
 aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o build/obj/dev-gpio.o -c -fno-pie -ffreestanding src/dev-gpio.c`
And modified the linking command to be: 
`build/rapi-boot/eos-init.bin: build/obj/init.o build/obj/dev-gpio.o` and have `build/obj/dev-gpio.o` added after the start , but it still doesn't work quite well.

Comment: *"It still doesn't work quite well"* is not a good description of the problem, but I will make some guesses and write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you now have a rule like this:

```
build/obj/dev-gpio.o: src/dev-gpio.c src/init.o src/eos.h
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o build/obj/dev-gpio.o -c -fno-pie -ffreestanding src/dev-gpio.c
```

One of those prerequisites (`src/init.o`) doesn't belong there. We remove it:

```
build/obj/dev-gpio.o: src/dev-gpio.c src/eos.h
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o build/obj/dev-gpio.o -c -fno-pie -ffreestanding src/dev-gpio.c
```

We put the compilation flags in a variable, to make the rule easier to read (and remove redundancy, since we use the same flags elsewhere:

```
CFLAGS := -fno-pie -ffreestanding 

build/obj/dev-gpio.o: src/dev-gpio.c src/eos.h
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o build/obj/dev-gpio.o -c $(CFLAGS) src/dev-gpio.c
```

And use the [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) `$@` and `$<` to remove more redundancy:

```
build/obj/dev-gpio.o: src/dev-gpio.c src/eos.h
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o $@ -c $(CFLAGS) $<
```

*Once we verify that that rule works,* we modify the linking rule to include the new object file (`build/obj/dev-gpio.o`):

```
build/rapi-boot/eos-init.bin: build/obj/init.o build/obj/dev-gpio.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o eos-init.elf -nostdlib -fno-pie -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -T linker.ld -e start build/obj/init.o build/obj/dev-gpio.o
    ...
```

(I *suspect* I know how to remove the extra commands, but I'll leave them alone for now.)

And, again, use variables to clean it up:

```
build/rapi-boot/eos-init.bin: build/obj/init.o build/obj/dev-gpio.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o eos-init.elf -nostdlib $(CFLAGS) -nostartfiles -T linker.ld -e start $^
    ...
```

Further refinements are possible, but that's enough for now.

Comment: I am quite new to makefiles, and this was just something I rushed to understand in order to do my project. With a better understanding now and with the added variables to clear redundancy, it's a lot nicer to work with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I overthink things..

The correct makefile should be this:

```
    .PHONY: all build clean

build/rapi-boot/eos-init.bin: build/obj/init.o build/obj/dev-gpio.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o eos-init.elf -nostdlib -fno-pie -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -T linker.ld -e start build/obj/init.o build/obj/dev-gpio.o
    aarch64-linux-gnu-objcopy eos-init.elf -O binary -j .eos-* build/rapi-boot/eos-init.bin
    rm eos-init.elf

build/obj/init.o: src/init.c src/eos.h
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o build/obj/init.o -c -fno-pie -ffreestanding src/init.c

build/obj/dev-gpio.o: src/dev-gpio.c src/eos.h
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -o build/obj/dev-gpio.o -c -fno-pie -ffreestanding src/dev-gpio.c

build: build/rapi-boot/eos-init.bin
    dd if=/dev/zero of=build/eos.img count=100 bs=1M
    sudo losetup -D
    sudo losetup -fP build/eos.img
    printf "o\nn\np\n1\n\n\nt\nc\nw\n" | sudo fdisk /dev/loop0
    sudo losetup -o 1048576 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop0
    sudo mkfs.vfat -n EOS /dev/loop1
    sudo mount /dev/loop1 build/mnt
    sudo cp -r build/rapi-boot/* build/mnt/.
    sudo umount build/mnt
    sudo losetup -D

clean:
    if [ -f "build/rapi-boot/eos-init.bin" ]; then rm build/rapi-boot/eos-init.bin; fi
    if [ -f "build/eos.img" ]; then rm build/eos.img; fi
    if [ -f "build/obj/init.o" ]; then rm build/obj/*.o; fi
```

Added a rule for the second .c file 'dev-gpio.c' and added this to the linker rule up above as well as after the 'start' command.